# Wordpress - Colors not editing, even with !important?

Tags: php, wordpress

I use inspect element to know where the source code would be.
First, I tried `style.css` and found all the classes I'm looking for.
I changed color: pink !important; to whatever color I want.

It changes on Inspect Element, however, when updating style.css, it's not changing.
I also noticed that the file is under index.php ?
I checked it but it's just the main template.

I searched thru SO but my problem seems to be the source code is in `index.php` and not the code itself.

[image: COLOR]

Comment: Might try to clear browser cache and reload to see if the changes update.

Comment: I'm such an idiot lol that worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As Paul T. suggested, clearing browser cache will solve this.